# extract file HANDLE from Windows file descriptor or from FILE*

Tags: winapi, file-io

Is it possible to extract file HANDLE from  Windows file descriptor or from FILE* ?

As an example, FILE* is implemeted on top of file descriptors, and in turn file descriptors are implemented (on Windows) on top of HANDLEs. A FD can be extracted from FILE* using documented fileno() function. Extracting HANDLE from FD might be more hacking or more documented ....

Comment: Hmm why would people vote to close a legitimate question.

Comment: Some people are prejudiced against basic questions.

Comment: @Andrei: It WAS a bit hard to read originally.  Put a little more effort into spelling in the future, and people are more likely to put effort into finding you an answer.

Comment: @Lance, it's totally not a basic question. Ask 10 people whether (1) FDs have underlying HANDLE (2) is translation exported, 9 out of 10 won't know the answer.

Answer (score 20):

Yes. See the [`_get_osfhandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/get-osfhandle) function.

Comment: The inverse — [`_open_osfhandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts1c9x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) — *Associates a C run-time file descriptor with an existing operating-system file handle.*

Comment: And it seems that the result of _get_osfhandle should be casted to a HANDLE to make stuff work. Without the cast I get error messages (from gcc 6.3 in msys 2 compiling C++): error: invalid conversion from 'intptr_t {aka long long int}' to 'HANDLE {aka void*}'