# Can we do popen with non blocking fgets on pipe in Windows C++. Otherwise ca we use fcntl, select or poll API on File read

Tags: c++, windows, fgets, nonblocking

We implemented exec API with popen and fgets. As fgets is blocking API. The command executed through popen hangs or stuck, then main parent process gets blocked forever. To resolve this is there anyway to timeout on fgets API in windows C++.

In linux, using fcntl, poll or select API we can figure out status of pipe and timeout if it takes longer time. Do we have similar API's in Windows for synchronous IO.

Thank You
Sushma

Tried to implement popen API with overlapped IO. Used ReadFile API with overlapped Flag. implementation is little complex.

Looking for windows API if any available to timeout or cancel synchronous fgets.

Comment: `WaitForMultipleObjects` or `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents` can be used for such purpose, these perform similarly to `poll` or `select` on POSIX (though you only get one single active handle at a time). You need windows file handles for these, though – to get them see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746267/extract-file-handle-from-windows-file-descriptor-or-from-file).

Comment: There is `WaitForSingleObject` variant for as well – I personally, though, prefer the `Multiple` variants because these allow adding one additional event (e.g. via `WSACreateEvent`) that you might set explicitly yourself when the programme (thread) should wake up for another task, so you don't need to spuriously wake up via timeouts and check if the programme should e.g. exit (for this you could e.g. install a signal handler setting the event).